# sqlite filter values based on destinct values in another column

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a TABLE like this

```
unixdatetime INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  UserId TEXT,  Latitude TEXT    
1505144748                         ABC123        51.6N
1505309523                         ABC123        51.6N
1505320731                         BCD234        51.6N
1505378502                         BCD234        51.6N
1507382309                         BCD234        51.6N
```

I need to get a one Latitude result for each DISTINCT UserID, so my result would be `[(51.691N), (51.691N)]`

Im trying

```
c.execute('select DISTINCT Latitude from TABLE where UserID in (select DISTINCT UserID from TABLE)').fetchall()
```

But that only gives me 1 result, I understand thats because Im asking for DISTINCT Latitude, I just dont know how to ask SQLite for what Im looking for.  `max(Latitude)` does the same.

Comment: Which 1 result do you want for a user? The most recent?

Comment: That would be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use GROUP BY:

```
c.execute('select Latitude from TABLE group by UserId')
```

Comment: OK thanks, thats works, I had not properly understood what group by did and had failed to use it correctly in an earlier try